# How to call javascript function before the page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript

I want to zoom out to 85 % before the page is fully loaded. Now the code has a problem that the zoom only works if the page is fully loaded. 
I try to put it to the head of html, but it doenst works. 
Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
  window.onload = function zoom(){ document.body.style.zoom = "85%" }
```

Comment: Check this [Call js function before page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744639/call-javascript-function-before-page-loads)

Comment: @dota2pro `$(document).ready(` is triggered when the page is fully loaded, but the OP's requirement is a bit different. So, I don't think it is dup of the linked post you mentioned. Does it?

Answer (score 2):

Place this just after the opening `body` tag.

```
<script>
  document.body.style.zoom = "85%";
</script>
```

Without the code being wrapped in a function that is a callback to the `window.onload` event, it will execute as soon as it is encountered.

Comment: @AnatoliiParubets I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by "it will doing your html dirty". There is nothing wrong with this HTML. This is how to make code execute as soon as it is encountered, when no event exists.

Comment: This will not work in `head`. The `body` element hasn't been parsed at that point, so it's not part of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOMContentLoaded` event. It is fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

For example

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {});
```

Comment: It's unclear that `DOMContentLoaded` is what the OP wants. Depending on what/how many/how big the external resources are, there could be an insignificant time difference between this and `load`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much.  It works but somehow I have to wait until the page is fully load, then I can see that it zoom out to 85 %. So the picture looks like it jumping.

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {});